# Can't login to SQL Server with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've just installed SQL Server 2012 and open the SQL Server Management Studio and when I try to login this problem occurs:

> Can't connect to .....

My question is how can I know what is the server name?

And when I go to the SQL Server Configuration Manager I can't find the SQL Server services which should exist !!

Any answer ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the version SQL Express?

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS` as server name.

Comment: by the way, I have installed this en_sql_server_2012_express_management_studio_with_sp1_x86 on Windows 8 .

Comment: I tried to add some possibilities, check it out and let me know.

Comment: This worked for me http://badkr.blogspot.in/2015/01/cannot-login-to-sql-server-using.html. My Sql Server service was stopped, just started it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you installed SQL Express, the correct server name is:

```
127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS
```

or

```
YOURMACHINENAME\SQLEXPRESS
```

If that does not work there are some steps you can take:

Check if **the "SQL Server Browser" windows service is activated and running**:

- Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services
- Open "SQL Server Browser" service and enable it (make it manual or automatic, depending on your needs)
- Start it.

If that too does not work, you can also check if the TCP/IP protocol is enabled in your SQL Server instance. Follow these steps (tested for SS2012) to make sure:

- Open "**Sql Server Configuration Manager**" in "Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft SQL Server 2012\Configuration Tools\"
- Expand "SQL Server Network Configuration"
- Go in "Protocols for `<YourInstance>`"
- Enable TCP/IP

If you have any problem, check [this blog post](http://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/connecting-to-sql-server-using-jtds/) for details, as it contains screenshots and much more info.

That's it.

Comment: sorry but I can't found the 'SQL Server Browser'  in the services , i just found the SQL Server VSS Writer. also in my SQL Server Configuration Manager i didn't find 'Protocols for ...' . thanks.

Comment: What SQL Server services did you find there? I'm suspecting you did not install the local instance (SQL Server Express), just the SSMS. How big is that installer you used?

Comment: i didn't find any service! yes, i just download the sqlserve managment studio . it's about 962 MB.

Comment: There you go, you didn't install the SQL Server local instance. Download other installer. I know, that SSMS installer is misleading... You really need to download the installer **with** the local instance.

Comment: do I have to download the full sql server express edition with SP1 ?

Comment: do you suggest any site to download the require installer from it ?

Comment: I would resort to the official site: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579 ;

Comment: @acdcjunior - Open "SQL Server Browser" service and enable it. Worked for me Thanks :)