# SQL Server 2014 instance issue: can't login

Tags: sql, sql-server, instance, sql-server-2014-express

Although solutions about recurrent server instance issues have been proposed on this forum, none of them are working for my case.

In SQL Server configuration manager, all seems to be fine:

1. SQL server services:

   - SQL server (SQLEXPRESS) is running
   - SQL server (SQLEXPRESS_V12), running as well
   - SQL server browser, running

   **however:**

   SQL Server agent (`SQLEXPRESS`) is stopped as well as SQL Server agent (`SQLEXPRESS_V12`). Initially their status were disabled (by default) and I changed them to automatic. Also when right-clicking and selecting 'start' both requests fail for some reasons and I wondering if there is a correlation with the login failure.

   What strikes me the most: I can login to `SQLEXPRESS` instance with Windows authentication without problem from SQL Server Management Studio, but not to `SQLEXPRESS_V12` instance with SQL Server authentication (login && password needed)
2. SQL server Network configuration

   Finally I confirm that TCP/IP are enabled for both `SQLEXPRESS` and `SQLEXPRESS_V12`

Best,

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?  Are you trying to login with WinAuth or SQLAuth?  Which server is causing the issue?

Comment: This isn't a programming-specific question: Suggest moving it over to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: sometimes your user gets corrupted , check using this `sp_change_users_login @Action='Report';` and fix using this `sp_change_users_login @Action='update_one', @UserNamePattern='userName', @LoginName='userName';`

Comment: @TTeeple:classical error `a network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to sql server. server was not found or was not accessible...(provider: SQL Network interfaces, error 26: error locating server/instance specified)`. Could this versatilty be attributable to an upgrade to windows 10 as  i had  never got instance issues in the past?

Comment: So what is the problem?  It sounds like you can connect to both instances.

Comment: @TTeeple: i can't connect only to SQLEXPRESS_V12 instance (server authentification)

Comment: You should modify your question a bit then.  All the extra fluff makes it sound like everything is fine.  Did you check to see if Mixed Auth is enabled on that instance?

Comment: @TTeeple: updated. how do you check Mixed Auth? I never paid attention to that, since all was working fine before. it was a binary check using management studio: windows or sql server authentification

Comment: @TTeeple: I've just checked the log and can confirm `2015-09-01 21:24:42.71 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.`

Comment: FYI `SQLAgent` is not included with SQL Express versions.  That is why it is disabled by default -- enabling it will do nothing, it won't start.  `SQLAgent` is uses for scheduling jobs, it is not related to authentication.  Did you try browsing in SSMS for SQL instances?  it's not likely the actual instance is named `<machine>\SQLEXPRESS_V12` unless you specified that on install.

Comment: @JiggsJedi: Thanks for the info on `SQLAgent`, I was not aware about it. In regards to `<machine>\SQLEXPRESS_V12` I confirm it was my specification to distinguish it from a previous instance name `SQLEXPRESS`. As I mention `\SQLEXPRESS_V12` used to working fine as i have been using it since ages, saving the credentials to avoid any mistakes/typos etc.

Comment: What happens if you try `<ip address>\SQLEXPRESS_V12` ?  (saw it on another thread)... and are you confirming SQLServer is starting after every reboot?  Seems you're not alone win Windows10 woes.  Does the instance name show under browse>local>db in SSMS?

Comment: @JiggsJedi: no improvement with `<ip address>\SQLEXPRESS_V12`. I've also added port 1433 to windows firewall (same). I confirm the instance name is shown as follows: `COMPUTERNAME\INSTANCENAME` here `COMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESSV12`

Comment: @JiggsJedi: by curiousity; Any 'plausible' idea why I can log with windows authentification and notwith sql server's one? this testifies that the instance name SQLEXPRESS is found as opposed to SQLEXPRESS_V12. Very bizzare, isn't it?

Comment: @JiggsJedi: Apologies for a 'naivety'. `<ip address>\SQLEXPRESS_V12` works indeed. I  finally used `127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS_V12` based on  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621754/cant-login-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication) rather than the IP retrieved from [link] (http://www.ipchicken.com/). Many Thanks, it was a pretty tough case. Cheers.